# DevExpress RepositoryItem in WPF

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I am trying to port some code using DevExpress XtraGrid to Wpf. What is the equivalent of  RepositoryItem in their WPF suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [DXGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/) each editor has the helper class (the [BaseEditSettings](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsSettingsBaseEditSettingstopic) descendant) responsible for the editor's functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I figured it out couple of hours after asking the question, but was too tired to add an answer.